# Why is the normal force always perpendicular to the surface rather than opposing the force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram

[image]

In the classic "box on a ramp" example, how does it know which way is perpendicular? If the normal force was opposite of gravity, the force being applied, it would still constrain the box from intersecting with the ramp. I've heard that it is the average of all the molecules pushing back against the object, but why do they average out to always be perpendicular?

[image]

> Edit: I am assuming zero friction in this case-- I'll paste in a restatement of the question I wrote into a comment:
>
> *Imagine both the box and ramp are made of perfectly frictionless ice. Why do the electromagnetic forces keeping the two from intersecting not push in direct opposition to gravity, canceling out both the normal and tangential components? Why do they only cancel out gravity's normal component and not its tangential?*

Imagining it on a molecular scale, why do we observe the second image and not the first? I know my drawing is bad, but thats supposed to be a lattice of atoms (the slope) with the box's weight pushing down on it. The box's weight is pushing straight down on the atoms, so why don't they push back straight up?

> Edit: removing this section as it is largely irrelevant and a bad example

> [image]
>
>  And what if there isn't multiple points to average? What if the object only touches the slope at a single point? How does it know which way is perpendicular?

And I know a lot of these "laws" exist because "thats what we observe," I just want to understand *why* we observe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Imagining it on a molecular scale, why do we observe the second image and not the first?

The first image is fine. We *choose*, for convenience, to separate some of those drawn force vectors into components **normal** to the surface and tangential to the surface.

> What if the object only touches the slope at a single point? How does it know which way is perpendicular?

It has no idea at all. The constituent molecules simply respond according to the net force applied to them.

Nature doesn't care if we decompose vectors or about any of our directional conventions, but these tools help us decouple, for example,

- the resistance to the object and the ramp plunging directly into each other (which depends strongly on the bulk stiffness and strength)

from

- the resistance to sliding between the object and the ramp (which depends strongly on the surface roughness and adhesion),

and these phenomena often have different origins in Nature.

Comment: Ah! So the normal force is only one component of the total contact force, and not all of it? That makes so much more sense. However, that also begs the question: If the contact force directly opposes gravity as shown in the first drawing of the second image, then why is an object on a slope not in equilibrium? What makes the tangential contact force (friction I assume) weaker than the tangential gravitational force, while the gravitational and contact forces are equal in the normal direction?

Comment: "*...then why is an object on a slope not in equilibrium?*" It is in your image, judging roughly by the lengths of the vectors you drew in black and red. In other words, you drew vectors incorporating a sufficiently large frictional force that the block doesn't slide (or perhaps it's bonded to the ramp). If the frictional force isn't sufficient, then the vectors will need to tilt, and that will result in the block accelerating down the ramp. Make sense?

Comment: I should've phrased that differently, I meant _"...why isnt **any** object on **any** slope not **always** in equilibrium?"_ The contact force on a flat plane is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to gravity, so then I expand that same concept to an inclined plane. But then that would mean nothing would ever slide down a slope under gravity, as if the vectors of gravity and contact forces are exactly opposite like that both their normal and tangential components would always cancel out to zero. I know this can't be true, but I can't find the hole in my logic.

Comment: I wasn't even trying to consider sources of friction other than the objects resisting intersecting with each other when I made that sketch, I was trying to only draw the same normal/contact force that makes me not fall through this box I'm sitting on. I was ignoring the additional forces that would stop it from sliding forever if I got up and kicked it. _"If the frictional force isn't sufficient, then the vectors will need to tilt..."_ This is the part I don't understand-- I don't see what would lead the vectors to tilt and not always perfectly oppose gravity

Comment: I'll put it another way: Drawing a force vector $F$ rising **vertically** from a slope of angle $\alpha$, as you did in the first image, implies that (1) the upward force $F$ must match the downward weight of the object, as the slope prevents the object from falling straight down. OK, no problem; the slope material is essentially rigid. But it also implies through trigonometry that (2) the friction force equals $F\sin\alpha$. If that much friction force doesn't arise at that interface from the normal force of $F\cos\alpha$, then the vector doesn't get to be vertical. Does this clarify?

Comment: It doesn't, I think I got the wrong idea from your original answer-- I was attempting to omit friction entirely (which to be fair I didn't explicitly state) and added friction force makes my first drawing possible. I'll try restating it to get to the crux of my misunderstanding: imagine both the box and ramp are made of perfectly frictionless ice. Why do the electromagnetic forces keeping the two from intersecting not push in direct opposition to gravity, canceling out both the normal and tangential components? Why do they only cancel out gravity's normal component and not its tangential?

Comment: If you specify that the surfaces are frictionless, how would a force push upward vertically on the slope (magnitude $F$, with normal component $F\cos\theta$ and tangential component $F\sin\theta$)? The surfaces can't sustain a tangential load—that's what "frictionless" means.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm wasting your time asking question after question, but I still don't have a grasp on it. Friction is caused by the microscopically jagged parts catching on each other, or by bonds trying to form, right? If neither of those specific phenomena occurred, why does the force caused by the electromagnetic repulsion of atoms not wanting to be inside each other not always generate that aforementioned F sin α "friction force" in addition to the F cos α "normal force"? By saying it is frictionless I'm simply trying to isolate this single interaction

Comment: "*why does the force caused by the electromagnetic repulsion of atoms not wanting to be inside each other not always generate that aforementioned F sin α "friction force*"? The friction force direction doesn't involve atoms impinging on each other, does it? They just slide past each other.

Answer (score 3):

The force of interaction between the object and incline can always be resolved into components parallel and perpendicular to the incline. We call the perpendicular component the "normal force", so it is this way by definition. Usually we call the parallel component "friction". It does not require the object or incline to "know" anything; the net interaction force does not need to be purely along either of these directions.

Answer (score 0):

It's a so-called contact force which is mediated by electromagnetic forces, often modeled as the van der Waals interaction for a solid, which produces repulsion that rises in strength inversely proportional to distance.

In your "molecule ball" picture, the closest parts get pushed away with the greatest tenacity -- which on the whole results in a normal force that is to a good approximation away from the surface.